# React Store is returning null for value of `this`

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm running into an issue where `this` is returning `null` in my store for my React component. I believe I need to bind this, but I am unsure. I'm also using React Router and have my component set up in a wrapper so I'm able to pass props to it. Any help is appreciated!

COMPONENT

```
import React from 'react';
import PaymentStore from './../store/paymentStore';

class InitialPaymentScreen extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
  }
  render() {
    console.log(this.props)
    return (
       <div className="payment-form-submit" onClick={this.props.store.init}>Next</div>
    );
  }
}

class PaymentForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <section className="main-content payment-form-wrapper">
        <InitialPaymentScreen store={this.props.store}/>
      </section>
    );
  }
}

export default class PaymentFormWrapper extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <PaymentForm store={PaymentStore} mode="foo"/>
    );
  }
}
```

STORE

```
let PaymentStore = {
  handleClickNext() {

    console.log("hello")

  },
  init() {
    console.log(this) // returns null
    this.handleClickNext(); // cannot read property of null
  },
};

export default PaymentStore;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you need to bind it indeed. You can do that by changing

```
<div className="payment-form-submit" onClick={this.props.store.init}>Next</div>
```

to

```
<div className="payment-form-submit" onClick={this.props.store.init.bind(this.props.store)}>Next</div>

# or

var init = this.props.store.init.bind(this.props.store);
<div className="payment-form-submit" onClick={init}>Next</div>
```

Alternatively, if `InitialPaymentScreen` only needs `init` from `store`, the binding could happen in `PaymentForm`, and `InitialPaymentScreen` could only receive the function.

The binding needs to be done because javascript is, well, unique in some ways.

Generally, a function's `this` is bound to literally what's it being called from. In your case, `store.init()` means the `init` function has `this` as store.

Now, if you assign `store.init` to a variable and call that, it doesn't know what's `this`! (`this` is probably the most common issue for people learning JS) — because during invocations, it tries to infer `this` by seeing which object that function is stored in.

To get make the function know what's its context then, you have two options basically:

a. `fn.bind(something)`, which returns a bound function, or

b. create an anonymous function which invokes that one

Comment: Awesome, works like a charm. Could you clarify why I must bind this?

Comment: Sure, I've just updated my answer with some background!